# Unable to insert data in MySQL from PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to inser json data in MySQL database using the code below but getting values like Array[0][0],0.000 etc. can someone please suggest a solution.

The values in the variables are correct as the echo in loop is displaying the correct values in browser.

Thanks.

[EDIT]

The datatype of 'add' is varchar, for 'SN','imm' its int and rest is all double.

[/EDIT]

```
for($x=0; $x<$totaladdress; $x++)
{
echo $x;
echo "<br>add=";
echo $json_a[report][$x][0];


$sql = "INSERT INTO `report`.`tempmain` (`SN`, `add`, `last`,`imm`, `lastH`, `pa`, `unex`, `meg`, `bi`, `re`) VALUES (NULL, '$json_a[report][$x][0]','$json_a[report][$x][1][last]', '$json_a[report][$x][1][imm]', '$json_a[report][$x][1][lastH]', '$json_a[report][$x][1][pa]', '$json_a[report][$x][1][unex]', '$json_a[report][$x][1][meg]', '$json_a[report][$x][1][bi]', '$json_a[report][$x][1][re]');";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Try to echo the generated $SQL. might help you find the problem and help us figure out what's going on

Comment: Check error with `or die(mysql_error());`.

Comment: quote your array keys where array key is string. '$json_a[report][$x][1][last]' should become `'".$json_a['report'][$x][1]['last']."'` for example

Comment: can you var_dump your $json_a?

Comment: Your query will fail if one of your variables contain a `'`, because there is no escaping. Switch to mysqli or PDO with prepared statements. For debugging now, you can try to change `mysql_query($sql);` to `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @Askanison4 on $SQL echo

INSERT INTO `report`.`tempmain` (`SN`, `add`, `last`, `imm`, `lastH`, `pa`, `unex`, `meg`, `bi`, `re`) VALUES (NULL, 'Array[0][0]','Array[0][1][last]', 'Array[0][1][imm]', 'Array[0][1][lastH]', 'Array[0][1][pa]', 'Array[0][1][unex]', 'Array[0][1][meg]', 'Array[0][1][bi]', 'Array[0][1][re]');


@MarcelBalzer none of the variables contain ' only alphanumeric and decimal values.

Comment: or die(mysql_error());  does not give any error. The values are populated in database but they all are 0

Comment: Well, what should the database do, if you insert strings but the type of the field is int or double? Of course they are 0.

Comment: @MarcelBalzer so do I need to remove quote from non varchar values ? but varchar value is also incorrect it is "Array[0][0]" in database.

Comment: But Array [0][0] is nothing else than text. It's not the value of this array. So it's a varchar. And if you remove the qoutes this won't change.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `report`.`tempmain` (`SN`, `add`, `last`,`imm`, `lastH`, `pa`, `unex`, `meg`, `bi`, `re`) VALUES (NULL, '$json_a[report][$x][0]','$json_a[report][$x][1][last]', '$json_a[report][$x][1][imm]', '$json_a[report][$x][1][lastH]', '$json_a[report][$x][1][pa]', '$json_a[report][$x][1][unex]', '$json_a[report][$x][1][meg]', '$json_a[report][$x][1][bi]', '$json_a[report][$x][1][re]');";
```

Is inserting `$json_a` as an array and is not interpreting the rest. Try:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `report`.`tempmain` (`SN`, `add`, `last`,`imm`, `lastH`, `pa`, `unex`, `meg`, `bi`, `re`) VALUES (NULL, '".$json_a['report'][$x][0]."','".$json_a['report'][$x][1]['last']."', '".$json_a['report'][$x][1]['imm']."', '".$json_a['report'][$x][1]['lastH']."', '".$json_a['report'][$x][1]['pa']."', '".$json_a['report'][$x][1]['unex']."', '".$json_a['report'][$x][1]['meg']."', '".$json_a['report'][$x][1]['bi']."', '".$json_a['report'][$x][1]['re']."');";
```

I.e. rather than doing:

```
$sql = "some sql $json_a[report][$x][1][pa] other sql"
```

do

```
$sql = "some sql ".$json_a['report'][$x][1]['pa'] ." other sql";
```